# Unable to display output from matplotlib using conda through WSL

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, anaconda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to run ToPy (Topology Optimisation) program using anaconda on wsl.
So, I created an environment with python-2.7 and all other programs recommended by [ToPy](https://github.com/williamhunter/topy/releases/tag/0.4.1).

I am running into an error with Display output from wsl to Xming.
After some stressful debugging I came to the conclusion that matplotlib I installed on the anaconda environment is not supporting the output. (I initially thought its an error with Tkinter but it worked when I tried it on python-2.7 and python3, and I came to the conclusion that matplotlib is the issue after running a test code[below] on vscode using both python interpreters)

Test code: test.py

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
plt.plot(t, s)

plt.title('About as simple as it gets, folks')
plt.show()
```

This code works in wsl (not conda) and gave me an output. worked in conda with python3; gave me an output through XMing. But failed to give me output with python-2.7.15
I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "optimise.py", line 20, in <module>
    optimise(argv[1])
  File "optimise.py", line 16, in optimise
    topy.optimise(t)
  File "/home/sree/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/topy/optimisation.py", line 67, in optimise
    _optimise(topology)
  File "/home/sree/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/topy/optimisation.py", line 43, in _optimise
    create_2d_imag(t.desvars, **params)
  File "/home/sree/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/topy/visualisation.py", line 56, in create_2d_imag
    figure() # open a figure
  File "/home/sree/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 533, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/sree/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 161, in new_figure_manager
    return cls.new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, fig)
  File "/home/sree/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py", line 1046, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
    window = Tk.Tk(className="matplotlib")
  File "/home/sree/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1819, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":0.0"
```

I checked with `echo $DISPLAY` returns `:0.0`
I tried `xeyes` and other output while in conda env with python-2.7.15; I get output through XMing but not the matplotlib plots.

I really need to finish this project soon; any help would be greatly appreciated.

TLDR; I use anaconda environment (with python-2.7.15) inside wsl and tried to run ToPy solver; Failed to get output only when working with matplotlib.

Sorry if I didn't word the question precisely; I recently started coding and am new to this forum.

Comment: Hmm, I can't reproduce your problem. I have WSL2, Ubuntu 20.04, and I'm using MobaXTerm. I installed the miniconda-latest using pyenv (python 2.7.18), installed matplotlib with conda, then ran your code, with Qt and Tkinter, and both outputted ok. When I use `echo $DISPLAY`, I get a local IP address. Did you try reinstalling this python version to see if that fixes it? Could you try your test code with some slightly different version?

Comment: I can't actually. The ToPy libraries use python-2.7. was suggested against updating.
you got an output of a sine curve with python-2.7?

Comment: No, I mean a different python 2.7, like 2.7.18, that shouldn't mess anything with the code. Or a completely new environment, installed from scratch. Then again, do you need to see the output? Can't you suppress showing it, and look at a saved image?

Comment: Oh, and yes, I got the sine curve with python 2.7

Comment: I tried with Agg but can't exactly figure out how to supress it everywhere since the source code has outputs from various parts of the solver
I also tried to output just matplotlib code with sine curve which failed as well
I will try with python-3 and python-2.7.18 as you suggested. Thanks

Comment: @K.Cl Can you please brief me the process you followed please?

Comment: Also, are you familiar with jupyter notebooks? Or did you try other backends besides Agg and Tk? If you place `matplotlib.use(<backend>)` right at the start of your code, before importing anything, that should affect everything.

Comment: Brief you exactly on what part? What my setup is to install those different versions?

Comment: @K.Cl I tried using matplotlib.use('Agg') which still got me same error
Yes, I meant if you ran the code in an env with p-2.7?

Comment: Here's the commands I used: `pyenv install miniconda2-latest`, `pyenv local miniconda2-latest`, `conda install matplotlib`, `python test.py`. My current python version is `Python 2.7.18 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 23 2020, 22:42:48)`. If you run `conda create --name test python=2.7.18`, then try to run your code, you get the same error?

Comment: Also, try adding this to the beginning of your file: `import matplotlib`, `matplotlib.use('pdf')`. That should suppress every window.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU SO SO MUCH
Finally I got the results on ToPy

Comment: Congrats! What did you do so I can post an answer and have you validate it?

Comment: @K.Cl I just wrote an answer with the steps I followed. If you'd like to answer please do so. and Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For someone with a similar issue
I got it to working with just a python update from 2.7.15 to 2.7.18

I did run  `conda install -c conda-forge r-tcltk2`
It changed some conflicts and I got a `glibcxx_3.4.26 not found` error later but after updating linux distro and python to 2.7.18. I can run my simulations

Thanks a ton for prompt help

EDIT:
[This](https://github.com/williamhunter/topy/releases/tag/0.4.1) should help someone with installation issues